# How to use lftp to delete old files before downloading new?

Tags: raspbian, lftp

I am running lftp on Raspbian

I have 100GB of content on the remote site and 100GB space available on my SD card so I need to delete files not present at the remote site from the SD card before downloading new content.

How can I achieve this?

```
#!/bin/bash
login="username"
pass="password"
host="server.feralhosting.com"
remote_dir="/folder/you/want/to/copy"
local_dir="/cygdrive/s/lftp/somefolder/where/you.want/your/files/"

base_name="$(basename "$0")"
lock_file='/tmp/'"$base_name"'.lock'
trap 'rm -f '"$lock_file"'' SIGINT SIGTERM
if [[ -e "$lock_file" ]]
then
  echo "$base_name is running already."
  exit 1
else
  touch "$lock_file"
  lftp -u $login,$pass $host << EOF
  set ftp:ssl-allow no
  set mirror:use-pget-n 5
  mirror -c -P5 --log='/var/log/'"$base_name"'.log' "$remote_dir" "$local_dir"
  quit
EOF
  rm -f "$lock_file"
  trap - SIGINT SIGTERM
  exit 0
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

Add the --delete-first option, so this:

```
mirror -c -P5 --log='/var/log/'"$base_name"'.log' "$remote_dir" "$local_dir"
```

becomes this:

```
mirror -c -P5 --delete-first --log='/home/osmc/'"$base_name"'.log' "$remote_dir" "$local_dir"
```